# Vector subspace of functions where $f'(x) = 2f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given $V = \{f(x) : R \rightarrow R : f'(x) = 2f(x), \forall x \in R\}$.

I know how to do the proof about closure in regards to addition. But I'm not sure how to write the proof regarding multiplication by scalar.

$(\lambda f')(x) = \lambda 2f(x)$

$\lambda 2f(x) = \lambda [2f(x)]$

This way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\lambda\cdot f)' = \lambda \cdot f' = \lambda \cdot (2f) = 2 \cdot (\lambda\cdot f) \Rightarrow \lambda \cdot f \in V$

Comment: I was close, so I have to remember to look back at the eight axioms of vector spaces.

Comment: @0kelvin No, not the $8$ axioms of vector spaces, but the $3$ conditions for a subspace of a vector space.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I was referring to the fact that I have to look at the proofs, not to check for all 8 axioms one by one. I can see that I was missing the associativity and comutativity properties.